# Простой вопрос с js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пож. как сделать, чтоб моя заметка показывалась, только при условии, когда список задач пуст, в противном случае ее не было. Понимаю что нужно делать через условие if только, как написать условие что показывать сообщение когда ol не содержит li. Буду благодарен за помощь!

https://codepen.io/igor-solodownik/pen/xxqRbyL

```
let noteForEmptyList = document.createElement('p');
noteForEmptyList.classList.add('noteForEmptyList')
noteForEmptyList.textContent = 'Можете отдохнуть. Текущий список дел пуст:)'
todoList.append(noteForEmptyList)
```

Comment: напишите функцию, которая берет ваш `ol` и считает число дочерних элементов. Если 0, то показываете запись. Если больше то скрываете, очевидно. Вызывайте функцию при добавлении/удалении элементов. Алгоритм прост, но с чем у вас проблемы возникли?

Comment: Вообще не могу сообразить как ее написать. Чтоб посчитать кол-во дочерних элементов. Через цикл?

Comment: так погуглите, вдруг там какое-нибудь банальное `childElementCount` у элементов имеется.

Comment: Написал, так не работает   for (let i = 0; i < todoList.length; i++){
    if (todoList[i] = 0){
      let noteForEmptyList = document.createElement('p');
noteForEmptyList.classList.add('noteForEmptyList')
noteForEmptyList.textContent = 'Можете отдохнуть. Текущий список дел пуст:)'
todoList.append(noteForEmptyList)
    }
  }

Comment: и зачем вам динамически создавать этот текст, хотите побольше кода написать? вставьте его в верстку изначально и скрывайте/показывайте.

Comment: Хотя да. Добавил в html. Подскажите пож. почему только не срабатывает функция? При таком написании:

Comment: function testNote() {
  for (let i = 0; i < todoList.length; i++){
    count = todoList[i];
    if (count < 0) {
      console.log('Значение меньше 0');
    } else {
      console.log('Значение меньше 1 и более');
    }
  }
}

Comment: ее объявил и при удалении и при добавлении задач. Протестировал работают. Но, с этим циклом не работают

Comment: вы можете объяснить зачем вам цикл?

Comment: А, как узнать кол-во элементов. Делаю так, тоже не срабатывает. function testNote() {
  if (todoList.length == 0){
    console.log('Тут 0');
  } else {
    console.log('Тут 1 и более');
  }
}

Comment: Простите, просто с js совсем недавно работаю, все пытаюсь понять логику

Comment: И вы написали (напишите функцию, которая берет ваш ol и считает число дочерних элементов. Если 0, то показываете запись.), и (и зачем вам динамически создавать этот текст, хотите побольше кода написать? вставьте его в верстку изначально и скрывайте/показывайте.), но если я вставлю в верстку, а именно в ol, то 0 у меня никогда не будет уже и срабатывать функция тоже не будет. А, вставлять текст нужно в ol, так как он именно там и должен показываться( Делема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

задача решается примерно так

```js
let msg = document.getElementById("msg"),
    todo = document.getElementById("todo"),
    add    =  document.getElementById("add"),
    remove = document.getElementById("remove");
    
    
function updateMessage(){   
  msg.classList.toggle('hidden', todo.childElementCount > 0);   
}
    
add.addEventListener('click',function(){
  
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  todo.appendChild(li);
  li.textContent = 'item#' + todo.childElementCount;
  
  updateMessage();
});

remove.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(todo.lastChild){
    todo.lastChild.remove();
  }
  
  updateMessage();
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="msg">empty</p>
<ol id="todo">
</ol>

<button id="add">add</button>
<button id="remove">remove</button>
```